# Expand Tumblr shortened link

Tags: api, tumblr, url-shortener

I have a Tumblr link like this: http://tumblr.com/XXXXXXXX

In order to communicate with their API [I need the hostname](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#overview) of the blog, therefore I need to expand the link to the complete link. Something like: http://blogname.tumblr.com/post/XXXXXX

How can I expand a tumblr shortened link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Tumblr API, I do not believe it is possible as mentioned by [Derek Gottfrid](http://groups.google.com/group/tumblr-api/msg/5695f2a3410a3325). If you are using it within your app or service you can try looking at the headers.

For example in python, you can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
tumb = urllib2.urlopen('http://tumblr.com/XXXXXXXX')
print tumb.url
```

In PHP, you can use the [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) method

```
$url = 'http://tumblr.com/XXXXXXXX'
print_r(get_headers($url))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I answered on the thread. I might check the backend solutions, although I would prefere a straight API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it in Ruby. It needs to follow tumblr redirection. From http://tmblr.co/XXXXX to http://www.tumblr.com/XXXXX and lastly to the expanded URL. From [Net::HTTP documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def get_permalink(uri_str, limit=5)
  # You should choose better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri_str))
  case response
    when Net::HTTPOK then uri_str
    when Net::HTTPMovedPermanently
      get_permalink(response['location'], limit-1)
    when Net::HTTPFound
      get_permalink(response['location'], limit-1)
  end
end
```

Hope it helps someone